# TagLib-Sharp missing references: gdk & glib

Tags: reference, glib, gdk, taglib-sharp

I'd like to rebuild Taglib.dll from source code but in the solution there are some references missing.

I tried to re-add them with NuGet and it worked for some, but gdk-sharp and glib-sharp are posing problems:

- Gdk doesn't show up in "manage NuGet packages" (gtk neither)
- Glib won't install with error: 
  Could not find file 'C:\Users\kristof\AppData\Local\Temp\nuget\z0215i32.5gh\tools\native\v110\Win32\Debug\dynamic\glib-genmarshal.exe'.

I'm working on a Windows 8.1 computer with Visual Studio 2013. The installed frameworks are 4.5 and 3.5. Though 4.5 shows up in the programlist, while 3.5 is only marked in the features.

Thanks in advance, kind regards.

Link to screenshot:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRGs4.png

Comment: Looks like those packages are only required for the tests.  Not familiar with NuGet but maybe you can exclude the tests project.

Comment: I did got another issue:
"Error Generating Win32 resource: Error reading icon .../src access is denied".
Which I solved by deleting the taglib-sharp.suo file and by deleting the line <ApplicationIcon>.</ApplicationIcon> in src/taglib-sharp.csproj file.

So wow, many thanks Brian Nickel! The project build successfully

Comment: Thanks for the info but removing the . from <ApplicationIcon>.</ApplicationIcon> does the trick. I tried your solution first and the csproj file would not open.